# ORA-01720: Can't grant privileges on a view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g, sql-grant

I have an user with some tables and I granted privileges to three of them to another user. Now I need to create a view and grant select to another user, like this:

**User A**

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE_A TO USER_B WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE_B TO USER_B WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE_C TO USER_B WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**User B**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_XYZ AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C;

GRANT ALL ON V_XYZ to USER_C;
```

This give the folowing error:

```
ORA-01720: "grant option does not exist for '%s.%s'"

*Cause:    A grant was being performed on a view or a view was being replaced
           and the grant option was not present for an underlying object.
*Action:   Obtain the grant option on all underlying objects of the view or
           revoke existing grants on the view.
```

Comment: The error message seems very clear.  What is your question?

Comment: I want help. I gave grant option from USER_A to USER_B and now in USER_B I can't grant privileges to another user. Maybe that's something easy that I'm not looking.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the error message.  It literally tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: In my case the issue was due to fact that underlying table in the select statment of the view was not partitioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask ALL privileges to be given to USER_C, but only 4 have been granted to you to the underlying tables. Try either to grant ALL PRIVILEGES from A to B, or to restrict the grant from B to C on SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving:

```
GRANT select ON V_XYZ to USER_C;
```